# YouTube API：Cannot make the second request using the same access_token

Tags: php, python, youtube-api

I am trying to get data using youtube analytic api. After I got the access_token, I can use it to make a request and get the user's info, here is the python request:

```
newurl='https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/default?'
token={'v':'2.1', 'access_token':access_token}
urll = newurl + urllib.urlencode(token)
result = urllib.urlopen(newurl + urllib.urlencode(token)).read()
```

then, I tried to use the same access_token to make the second request like this:

```
newurl2='https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/analytics/v1/reports'
newtoken={'v':'2.1', 
      'start-date':'2010-10-10',
      'end-date': ###current time###,
      'metrics':'views,comments,likes,dislikes,shares',
      'ids':'channel==' ###user_id###,
      'access_token':access_token}
result = urllib.urlopen(newurl2 + urllib.urlencode(newtoken)).read()
```

but here I got a error:

```
"code": 401,
"message": "Invalid Credentials"
```

I can successfully make the second request when I am using PHP, and I cannot figure out why this got an error using python, could someone help me?? Thanks!!

Comment: looks like going to www.googleapis.com doesn't even work.  Perhaps they're down at the moment?

Comment: @Jeff but it works in my PHP code...

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak for the API calls, but it looks like you're missing a '?' at the end of newurl2.

Answer (score 0):

I would highly suggest using the python gapi client library for this, as it will handle all the oauth flow for you.

I'm confused about the v=2.1 parameter - the analytics API has only just reached V1, and there is no v API. I haven't tried using the V2 data api along with the new analytics API, the V3 data API and V1 analytics apis are very similar and I would personally stick to using them together.

Finally, I would check which oauth2 scopes you have got an access token for - the data and analytics APIs will require different scopes (you'll need "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/yt-analytics.readonly" for analytics)